# What should our SE site logo be?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, design

When we successfully emerge from beta we'll be able to help design what the site looks like. Why not take some pride in the site and start talking about that now?

Try to keep one idea per answer so we can vote them up and down independently. Multiple answers from the same person if you have multiple ideas is perfectly fine on the Meta site.

See also [the separate topic of the background and overall look of the site](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93/what-should-our-se-theme-background-look-feel-be).

Comment: Are we downvoting the ideas we don't like? Or just upvoting ones we do like?

Comment: @victoriah: both. I'll edit the question text. feel free to comment as well

Answer (score 15):

A **generic visa stamp**, the old-school small circular / rectangular ones. Sidesteps the issue of favouring any form or transport, small enough for a logo.

Comment: It favours international travel but its a great idea.

Comment: I favour this over the bestickered suitcase, as it is much cleaner, and will work well as a smaller logo.

Comment: It might be time for some of us with drawing or gfx skills (ie not me) to mock up versions of both to see how these two front runners might look.

Comment: I like this, but it's kind of specific to international travel.

Comment: I was going to suggest this, but it seems you already had this idea.

Answer (score 10):

A suitcase with a lot of stickers on it. (Like about half the hits on [this image search](http://www.bing.com/images/search?q=suitcase%20destinations&qs=n&sk=&form=QBIR).)Even though nobody uses stickers on the suitcase to show where to send it, the image is recognizable.

Comment: An old steamer style suitcase would be neat, and should fit well with the proposed 'old map' theme.

Answer (score 3):

A **globe** or **world map**.

- **Pros**: Definitely related to travel. Indicates that travel within any country is in the scope of the site.
- **Cons**: Already a bit overused on the internet to show world-wide connectivity, internationalization, etc. More suitable to international than domestic travel.

Answer (score 3):

Treasure map kind of graphic (worn out yellowish paper) with the world map. Indicating the search of treasures (help on getting to a treasure). Or probably a library or collection of treasures maps.

Comment: I think maps of various kinds would make a great background/theme but would be difficult as a logo.

Answer (score 2):

I just thought, how about we use a sextant?

A lot of other travel sites have passport stamps as their logo.

It would have to be a simplified image, but I think it would be unique.

We could do a small, two-color version (obviously more basic) of this:

[image]

Comment: +1, I like the idea. I just hope people don't misunderstand this to be a giant swinging pendulum-blade, out of Edgar Allen Poe's *The Pendulum*. ;)

Comment: @Ankur Haha, that is a concern.

Comment: Nice! Or an astrolabe!

Comment: Huh, this keeps getting downvoted. I am curious why? Would anyone who tossed a -1 care to tell me?

Comment: -1, it doesn't remind me of travel in any way.

Comment: @karinqe A sextant doesn't remind you of traveling? I have a feeling that might be a common sentiment. Maybe I read too much.

Comment: @Ginamin It reminds me of ship navigation, but not on first sight. I had to think about how this connects to travel. A logo should symbolize travel in such a way that most users recognize it without thinking and automaticly associate it with travelling. This doesn't do the job.

Comment: On the other hand, it would look good with a background of old maps.

Comment: @karinqe Fair enough. Comments always welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

A **compass**.

- **Pros**: definitely related to travel. Easy to design even for small sizes such as favicons.
- **Cons**: Might be ambiguous with some other existing or potential SE sites relating to geography.

Comment: I think this is ideal solution. THere is not much sites about geography, and compass is a symbol of answer for the question "Where am I"?

Comment: I thought I had seen it around SE and indeed the GIS SE uses a compass as its logo: http://gis.stackexchange.com/

Comment: OOOOOOpps, My bad :(

Answer (score 1):

A circle with 4 items on it - a hitch-hiker's thumb, an icon of a map, an icon of a hotel and an icon of a plane.  With travel.stackexchange emblazoned across the middle.

Or you know, something like that. I'm just feeling something different than a google image search result might be nice ;)

Comment: Combining this sort of iconography into a seal along with the Visa stamp idea posted by @ankur seems like an awesome idea to me.

Comment: Would we manage to pack all this information into a logo the same size as the other SE sites use?

Comment: Good idea, but not sure whether so many 'ideas' can be fitted into a logo small enough.

Answer (score 1):

**A pair of hiking boots.**

Pretty much every form of travel involves some walking.

It doesn't really fit business travel though.

Comment: Even for non-business / leisure travel, not every traveller or destination will identify with hiking boots.

Answer (score 0):

A flying bird. The freedom of travelling, you can fly to wherever you want.

Comment: I thought of an aeroplane but it was too much favouring one mode of travel. A bird avoids that problem nicely!

Comment: I was thinking about trains haha

Comment: Crisscrossing lines which are actually roads, train tracks, jetstreams, and bow waves might be nice (err for the background not the logo)!

Comment: that is cool too!!

Comment: It might be time to start the background/theme/look and feel thread...

Answer (score -2):

New option:

A map - I know people have said it's hard to pick one for the logo, so why not just one of the globe?

If so, a map of the globe, with a simple icon in the middle.

This could be a hitch-hiker's thumb, or a question mark?, or even one of those graduation hats to indicate 'qualified' (cough) answers :)

In front: Travel.Stackexchange, or whatever the new domain is if created.

Comment: Ah yes a globe wearing a mortarboard. Could be original.

Comment: OK so it's not original but I don't know if any competing sites use it: http://www.google.com.au/search?q=globe+wearing+mortarboard&hl=en&safe=off&prmd=ivns&source=lnms&tbm=isch&ei=lW4dTuffE9HHtAbizbGyDQ&sa=X&oi=mode_link&ct=mode&cd=2&ved=0CAsQ_AUoAQ&biw=853&bih=447

Comment: Uh, http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/72/what-should-our-se-site-logo-be/74#74

Comment: more than just a globe or world map, we've already moved it towards a capped globe, as per hippietrail's comments above.  I like the idea, and am not aware of any other competing or otherwise sites that use it.  It could be changed if that were found to be the case.