# What should our SE theme / background / look & feel be?

Tags: discussion, design

Now that [the logo question](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72/what-should-our-se-site-logo-be) is getting some attention it's time to start discussing the rest of our site's look for its life beyond beta.

Try to keep one idea per answer so we can vote them up and down independently. Multiple answers from the same person if you have multiple ideas is perfectly fine on the Meta site.

Comment: Related: http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/72/what-should-our-se-site-logo-be

Answer (score 9):

How about a background of various kinds of maps of different styles and ages strewn about?

Answer (score 5):

For part of the theme I had the idea of crisscrossing lines formed by a stylized road, train track, jetstream, and bow wave. Perhaps as a border or just here and there were straightish lines are needed?

Comment: probably this can be combined with the photos and maps idea by @VMAtm

Answer (score 4):

Background can be some collage contains photos and maps, especially old ones - with many dark sides on them:

[image][image][image][image]

Comment: Photos of the most iconic travel destinations like the Eiffel Tower and Taj Mahal?

Comment: Yes, something like that

Comment: I like the idea of maps, but not of photos, simply as it would give the site more of an emphasis on photography, and the types of travel that favour it.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not too fussed - I'd like it to be simple, possible a faded map, old school sepia style.

***But if it IS a map - there had better be a "Here be dragons!" on it somewhere!***

***[image]*** :)

Actually - I have no idea what the copyright is on this image, but I kinda like it ;)

Comment: That is the tattoo we each have across our backs right?

Answer (score 3):

Growing on Hippietrail's idea, what if we just have it as one old looking map. Like the old sea-farers maps. The background could be weathered parchment and the borders dark brown lines. Something like [this](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_p2KqxkFzn6A/S_ul-EIE8UI/AAAAAAAAAI0/nXc0GLsqSkA/s1600/old-world-map.jpg).

Comment: That might end up looking similar to English Language & Usage SE.

Comment: Ah yes, however lots of photos I think will be too busy.

Comment: Anything busy looking could be very very faint in the background which may or may not look good but would be worth experimenting.

Comment: @Ankur Also, I don't think there is anything wrong with similar to another SE site as long as it is distinct.

Answer (score 3):

An alternate theme from maps would be something in the style of transport timetables: trains, planes, boats, subways, ...

Answer (score 1):

Related to this [question](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173/look-of-the-favorite-question-icon) the favorite icon is a topic, too :-)

Comment: Ah yes we could possibly go with the first or second runner up in the logo vote.