# Look of the favorite question icon

Tags: discussion, design

IMHO the icon for "favorite question" looks like a pentagram ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagram)). It doesn't really bother me but maybe other people :-)

Comment: So...you're telling me this isn't a website about the occult? Ugh, what a misunderstanding!

Comment: Related: http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/93/what-should-our-se-theme-background-look-feel-be

Comment: @Ankur Man... I've been answered questions wrong then.

Comment: Just posted this as an answer, but I moved it to Ankur's link. Maybe we can use a sextant? I think that would fit well.

Comment: It's perfect for those whose favourite travel destination is to the stars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Totally agree. May be we can use some ideas from [this question](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72/what-should-our-se-site-logo-be) (especially visa stamp) for the new 'favorites'-icon?

Comment: Thank you for your agreement :-) Who's responsible to do push this topic further?

Comment: You should add this topic to the general discussion [here](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/93/what-should-our-se-theme-background-look-feel-be)

Comment: yes, and also for the "approved" icon. A visa stamp fits perfectly

Comment: A "stamp of approval" is perfect.

Answer (score 9):

It *is* a pentagram. In so far as it's a five-pointed star, and a pentagram is also a five-pointed star. I used to draw them in the margins of my math notebook as a kid... My late grandfather had a six-foot one welded together from angle irons that he hung and lit at Christmas. Why a five-pointed star I asked? Because a six-pointed star would have meant we were Jewish, he replied.

But I digress... It's part of the whole "sketchy" theme that beta sites are stuck with on SE. It's supposed to look like someone drew it, on graph paper, like those idle doodles I used to do instead of learning maths.

When your site graduates, you get something else. 'Til then, don't be sayin' nothin' bad 'bout my grampa...