# Alternative ideas for a logo for the graduated site

Tags: discussion, design, graduation

I think it's safe to say that more of us were more happy with Jin's [first presentation](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/832/design-for-travel-stack-exchange) of our site's logo and style than the [second attempt](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/travel-se-design-round-2).

The new abstract logo based on several superimposed pushpin graphics at varying angles isn't growing on some of us.

So I'd like to revisit our old question [What should our SE site logo be?](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72) to see if it's not too late to think up some alternative that might satisfy a greater portion of the community.

It's probably a good idea to go for variations on the old and new themes, but let's see.

If you have idea, please submit one idea per answer, preferably with an image, per answer so we can vote each idea up/down separately.

Answer (score 14):

Vote up if you liked Jin's original logo best:

[image: Jin's 1st logo]

Answer (score 0):

A pushpin whose round head is also a globe of the earth.

[image: pushpin globe] (This is just a rough sketch to get an idea!)

Comment: i like this but would prefer an animation of the globe map rather than an actual map...how about a GIF that actually rotates? ;)

Comment: There's not so many places where an animated logo could go. But why not as a little gimmick? (-:

Comment: how about an html5 rendition integrating google maps, which enables logo customization by focusing in on a user-defined place, and then passing that over to print on any medium?

Answer (score -7):

Vote up if you like Jin's new logo best.

[image: Jin's 2nd logo]

Comment: This logo with some alteration could be more beautiful.

Comment: -1: I can't avoid seeing a chicken's head in this logo.

Answer (score -8):

A pushpin with an aircraft and jetstream flying around it.

[image: pushpin jet] (I hate all computer image editing software so this is just a very rough idea.)