# Does the logo intentionally resemble a bird head?

Tags: discussion, design

I'm just a reader here, but every time I see the site's logo I see a bird's head looking to the left. As this is quite sublime I wondered: Is this intentional?

I did some digging and found the following two questions, however none of them features the actual logo…

- [What should our SE site logo be?](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72/what-should-our-se-site-logo-be/90#90)
  where the linked answer actually proposes a bird – then again it didn't receive an upvote *and* at least the current logo doesn't appear as an answer to this question at all…
- [Design for Travel Stack Exchange](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/832/design-for-travel-stack-exchange)
  somewhat comparable to the current logo design, but of course no bird at all

Comment: To me it's a map pinpoint thingy.

Comment: I see a map poinpoint thingy, but if I squint just the right way, I can see a bird wearing a bow tie (the tie is also its neck and half its mouth).

Comment: It was supposed to be a compass-like device, but many comparisons to rocket ships and other strange objects have been made. I'm wearing it on my tshirt at present, and the world map behind it possibly helps...

Comment: @AndrewT. Thank you! Through this question I found the one I was searching for, where the current logo is presented. Seems like a lot of other people are seeing ducks as well… ;)