# Link to question leads nowhere

Tags: discussion

I have not understood how everything works on this site, fully.
Yesterday, in the afternoon, I clicked on a question that seemed to ask something about this site's logo. I include a screenshot. I was redirected to a question here on meta but had no idea how these questions were related. Yesterday, in the later evening, I click on this question and got the message

> Page not found
>
> This question was voluntarily removed by its author

This ist still the case.
Out of sheer curiosity, can you please explain what happened? Why did the original question become a redirect to meta? Is there a way to read the original question? What was, eventually, deleted? The target of the redirection, here on meta?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question, now migrated to Meta, was deleted by OP, as it was a duplicate of a much earlier question.

As a relatively low rep user you can not see deleted questions, so you get the message you copied here.

This is the question of which it was a duplicate (or at least the one picked, as that is a duplicate in itself.)
[Does the logo intentionally resemble a bird head?](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4584/does-the-logo-intentionally-resemble-a-bird-head)

This is one of the reasons why we do not like people deleting their questions, as it leaves links which do not work anymore. But in some cases it is allowed.